# Chromebook BLE characteristic notifications issue

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, chromebook

I am developing a packaged app for chromebook. I am using BLE APIs to communicate with BLE devices. One of the modes of communication is request-response. Request is sent on a write characteristic and its response is received on another read characteristic. If multiple consecutive requests elicit same response then the notification is received only once.

For example consider request data bytes are [2, 5, 0] and its response is [3, 5, 0]. If I send [2,5,0] multiple times to the BLE device, and the device sends its response same number of times, in the chromebook app I see the characteristic notification only once.

Notification listener function:

```
chrome.bluetoothLowEnergy.onCharacteristicValueChanged.addListener(function (chrc) {
  logger.info("char value changed " + chrc.uuid + " value  " + chrc.value.byteLength + " address " + chrc.service.deviceAddress);
  var data = new Uint8Array(chrc.value);
  logger.info("Got char data " + data);
});
```

Char write function:

```
var myBytes = new Uint8Array([50, 20, 1]);
chrome.bluetoothLowEnergy.writeCharacteristicValue(charToWrite.instanceId, myBytes.buffer, function () {
  if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
    logger.error("Failed to write value: " + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
     return;
  }
  logger.info("First char write done");

  chrome.bluetoothLowEnergy.writeCharacteristicValue( charToWrite.instanceId, myBytes.buffer, function () {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
      logger.error("Failed to write value: " + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
      return;
    }
    logger.info("Second char write done");
  });
});
```

In above example, the notification response for second char write is never received (since the command is the same, the response is also the same).
If I send another command which elicits different response, then notification is received correctly.

Same BLE communication works fine on other platforms like Windows, MacOS. Thus we know that there is no device side issue. Chromebook seems to suppress notifications if same data is received on characteristic again and again.

I could not find a way in chromebook BLE API to change this behavior.

Has anybody else also seen this issue?

Comment: Can you post the code you have that produces this issue?

Comment: Updated the question with example code